# Converting monthly numerics to readable dates in R

Tags: r, datetime

How can set R to count months instead of dates when converting integers to dates?
 After reading several threads on how to convert dates in R, it seems like nobody has asked how it is possible to convert numeric dates if the numerics is given in monthly timeseries. E.g. 552 represents January 2006.

I have tried several things, such as using `as.Date(dates,origin="1899-12-01")`, but I reckognize that R counts days instead of months. Thus, the code on year-month number 552 above yields "1901-06-06" instead of the correct 2006-01-01.

Sidenote: I also want the format to be YEARmonth, but does R allow displaying dates without days?

Comment: can you give a sample of your data?

Comment: How does 552 represent January 2006 when counting starts in December 1899?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your starting date should be '1960-01-01'.

anyway you can solve this problem using the package `lubridate`.

in this case you can start from a date and add months.

```
library(lubridate)
as.Date('1960-01-01') %m+% months(552)
```

it gives you

```
[1] "2006-01-01"
```

you can display only the year and month of a date, but in that case R coerces the date into a character.

```
format(as.Date('2006-01-01'), "%Y-%m")
```

Comment: There also is class `yearmon` in package `zoo`.